# What does %% mean in a function name?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Looking at the output of `env`, I noticed that the following function is also listed.

```bsh
BASH_FUNC_mc%%=() {  . /usr/share/mc/mc-wrapper.sh }
```

The content of the /usr/share/mc/mc-wrapper.sh file is the following.

```bsh
MC_USER=`id | sed 's/[^(]*(//;s/).*//'`
MC_PWD_FILE="${TMPDIR-/tmp}/mc-$MC_USER/mc.pwd.$$"
/usr/bin/mc -P "$MC_PWD_FILE" "$@"

if test -r "$MC_PWD_FILE"; then
        MC_PWD="`cat "$MC_PWD_FILE"`"
        if test -n "$MC_PWD" && test -d "$MC_PWD"; then
                cd "$MC_PWD"
        fi
        unset MC_PWD
fi

rm -f "$MC_PWD_FILE"
unset MC_PWD_FILE
```

What do the `%%` characters mean in the function name? Do they make it the function invoked in specific cases, or do they allow me to call it differently from other functions?

If it makes any difference, I am using OpenSUSE 42.3, with Bash version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function name was crafted by `bash` updated as a response to the [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) vulnerability.

There was a function named `mc` that was exported and your `bash` version is renaming it by prepending `BASH_FUNC_` and replacing `()` by `%%`.

```
$ d() { date ; }
$ export -f d
$ env | grep %%
BASH_FUNC_d%% { date
```

Here is the `bash` patch by Florian Weimer that introduced this fix, dated Sept 25 2014:

> http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/att-693/variables-affix.patch

Note that a function name can contain almost any characters in `bash` just like a command name in general (i.e. a file name) so `%%` is definitely valid here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that bash is quite happy to use % characters in function names:

```
bash$ TEST%%() { echo test; }
bash$ TEST%%
test
```

whereas e.g. dash doesn't like them:

```
$ TEST%%() { echo test; }
dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name
```

So as far as I can tell, %% doesn't have any special meaning in a bash function name. It would be just like using XX instead. This is despite the definition of a `name` in the manpage:

```
   name   A word consisting only of  alphanumeric  characters  and  under-
          scores,  and beginning with an alphabetic character or an under-
          score.  Also referred to as an identifier.
```

Comment: But there is an equal `=` sign there after `%%`! Which causes assignment there.

Comment: That is just how `env` printed the function definition.