# Bash script function names containing double colon '::'

Tags: bash, syntax

I came across a Bash script today that has function names with double colons `::` in them, e.g., `file::write()` and `file::read()`. I've never seen this syntax before in a Bash script, and when I invoked the script it ran just fine (to my surprise).

After scouring Bash's man page on my system (and online) I cannot find anything in the documentation that supports this syntax for function names.  For example, the section `Shell Defined Functions` defines the syntax for a shell function to be

```
function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
```

and then (elsewhere in the manual) the token `name` is defined as

```
name   A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and
       underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character
       or an underscore.  Also referred to as an identifier.
```

There's no mention anywhere of the double colon syntax for function names.

The only other reference to this double colon syntax that I've found thus far is in this [Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s7.3-constants-and-environment-variable-names) (see the subsection `Naming Conventions > Function Names`) which recommends using the double colon syntax for function names in "packages"--e.g., `mypackage::myfunction()`.

Is this double colon syntax for function names a legitimate feature of the Bash shell, or is it perhaps an undocumented feature?  If it's legit, where is it documented in the Bash manual? I've looked and looked but I can't find anything about it in the manual. The closest I've found is the use of `::` in the `PATH` environment variable to add the current working directory to the search path.

**EXAMPLE**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function abc::def() {
    echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
}
abc::def
```

I tested this script on three different Linux distros, and on all three the script prints `abc::def` to stdout.

Comment: They're allowed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558080/what-are-double-colons-in-a-shell-script

Comment: One may also see `%%` in function names https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401166/what-does-mean-in-a-function-name

Comment: Thanks for the links. Odd. Prior to posting I searched for "bash double colon" (w/o the quotes) but didn't find anything. Apologies for re-asking an already answered question. .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a case of the documentation being stricter than the implementation, possibly in an attempt to lower the footgun factor. This has been [discussed here before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245331/shell-valid-function-name-characters); see also the [exhaustive test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041384/96588) establishing that for example `[}{` is a valid function name.

It may also be worth noting that `abc::def` is not a valid variable name:

```
$ abc::def=foo
bash: abc::def=foo: command not found
```

Comment: just to make it vividly clear - not `file::read` nor `[}{` is valid posix